# Map function to build an array from filtered object

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I'm trying to get my head around map functions currently without much success.

I currently have a list of objects and am trying to remap to a new object using the map function to return a map indexed by the created property with a list of wooids.

Having written my map function, I only seem to be returning the last time.

```js
const variants = [
{
   created: '2022-03-06',
    hashname: 'c78ba80402290724609a5e98c369c90984494152',
    hashobject: '80864e6329d5e305a512ace872ad7d56a3f41095',
    hashparent: '19c5d50ddddeb7c9a92469df78c47d9d611f1599',
    action: 'added',
    wooid: 7288
  },
{
   created: '2022-03-06',
    hashname: 'c78ba80402290724609a5e98c369c90984494152',
    hashobject: '80864e6329d5e305a512ace872ad7d56a3f41095',
    hashparent: '19c5d50ddddeb7c9a92469df78c47d9d611f1599',
    action: 'added',
    wooid: 7289
  }   
]

const res = Object.fromEntries(variants.map(k => [k.created, [k.wooid]]))
console.log(res)
```

Current output

```
{ '2022-03-06': [ 7289 ] }
```

Desired output:

```
{ '2022-03-06': [ 7289, 7288 ] }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm unsure how to dynamically populate the array to include all other entires (6 in total).

Comment: Sure the code works - however not as I'm anticipating.

I'm only getting back the last result - ideally I'm looking to return an object like so:

{ '2022-03-06': [ 7289, 7288 ] }

Comment: Sorry I've edited code to reflect

Comment: What determines the ordering in the resulting array? Why is `7289` first and not `7288` which appears first in the original array?

Comment: Nothing determines the ordering - I've just added to illustrate it capturing multiple values.

Comment: Ordering in arrays is significant so which order _should_ the values be in?

Comment: In that case sorted asc is fine

Comment: Sorted by `wooid` value? That's not what your example result shows

Comment: My main issue was capturing multiple values in the array, I hadn't got far enough to consider the sorting order of the array hence posting.

Sort asc on date would be the most logical for the context of how this will be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to build up your object. Check if you already have a key for each `created` value and if not, create an empty array. Then append the `wooid` value

```js
const variants = [{"created":"2022-03-06","hashname":"c78ba80402290724609a5e98c369c90984494152","hashobject":"80864e6329d5e305a512ace872ad7d56a3f41095","hashparent":"19c5d50ddddeb7c9a92469df78c47d9d611f1599","action":"added","wooid":7288},{"created":"2022-03-06","hashname":"c78ba80402290724609a5e98c369c90984494152","hashobject":"80864e6329d5e305a512ace872ad7d56a3f41095","hashparent":"19c5d50ddddeb7c9a92469df78c47d9d611f1599","action":"added","wooid":7289}]

const res = variants.reduce((acc, { created, wooid }) => ({
  ...acc,
  [ created ]: [
    ...acc[created] ?? [], // init to an empty array if unset
    wooid
  ]
}), {})

console.log(res)
```

This will collect `wooid` values by `created` in the order they appear in the original data.

Comment: Ah ok - so reduce is the better option in this instance - thanks for your help!

Comment: @user1387363 `Object.fromEntries()` is just a simplified _reduce_ anyway. You need something like the above in order to track existing `created` keys